# Uploadin files using Ajax - not receiving anything on server side

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using jQuery and Ajax. As far as I can tell everything is fine on the client side. I mean I can see the file being posted and all (using Firebug console) but on the server side I'm not receiving anything.
This is the code I'm using:

```js
var form_data = new FormData($('#share-music-form')[0]);
 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: window.baseurl+'/feeds/ajax/save_music/',
  data: form_data,
  success: function () {
   console.log('file DONE!');
  },
  xhrFields: {
   // add listener to XMLHTTPRequest object directly for progress (jquery doesn't have this yet)
   onprogress: function (progress) {
    // calculate upload progress
    var percentage = Math.floor((progress.total / progress.totalSize) * 100);
    // log upload progress to console
    console.log('progress', percentage);
    if (percentage === 100) {
     console.log('DONE!');
    }
   }
  },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(error);
     },
  processData: false,
  contentType: file.type
 });
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="share-music-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label class="fileContainer">
    <input type="file" name="text" id="music-file" />
   </label>

   <input type="text" name="status" id="status-music" class="pic-textarea">
  </form>
```

On the server side:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_FILE);
```

which outputs

> Array( text => the text i have posted )
>   Array()

Comment: Handle the errors that might be coming back from the AJAX call. This way you can be sure things are working as they're supposed to.

Comment: Just added error handling to no effect.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it working. It seems the problem was with the `contentType` which I had previously set to `file.type`.
By setting it to `false` It seems to have solved the issue.